# How to prove that the set of rational numbers that are not integers is countable and infinte?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is

Prove :
The set of rational numbers that are not integers is countable and infinte.

Well, Q \ Z is actually a subset of Q, thus |Q\Z| <= |Q| = א0

So this is a way to show that it is countable, but i can't seem to find a way
to show that it is infinte.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's enough to show that a subset of $\mathbb{Q - Z}$ is infinite. How about all numbers $1/n$ for positive integer $n \geq 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set of rationals of the form $n+\frac12,$ where $n\in\Bbb Z.$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the set $\{\frac{1}{n} \; | \; n \in \mathbb{N}, \; n >1\}$ is a set of numbers belonging to $\mathbb{Q}$ that contains no integers and is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

There are several not hard ways to prove this. Try to apply a one-to-one function of a countable set in Q in both questions, for instance a to 1/a and (a,b) to a/b (remember that 
a/b = na/nb and that the Cartesian product of countable is countable).